# Spring Rest Controller - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Tags: spring

I have defined a RestController(sample code below). I am reading json body from the request parameter. From my service i am invoking another Rest end point of a different application. I am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected"

```
def processPostRequest(request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity[String] ={
val requestURI = request.getRequestURI
val customURI = requestURI.substring("/abc/xyz".size)
val queryString = request.getQueryString
val queryParameters = extractQueryParameters(queryString)
val httpMethod = request.getMethod.toLowerCase
val inputStream = request.getInputStream
val requestBody = IOUtils.toString(inputStream)


val response = Service.processGraphRequest(customURI,httpMethod,queryParameters, requestBody)
new ResponseEntity[String](response,HttpStatus.OK)
```

}

I am getting the below exception.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3071) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.setOutboundHeaders(HttpUrlConnector.java:421) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.access$100(HttpUrlConnector.java:96) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:384) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:816) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:545) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444) ~[jersey-common-2.22.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681) ~[jersey-client-2.22.1.jar:?]

Can anyone help me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Share the body of method  Service.processGraphRequest(customURI,httpMethod,queryParameters, requestBody)